# Simple Products are not showing as associated in configurable products in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

Hope you are doing well.

I need to ask about how to set up a simple product to be able to show it to my configurable associated products.

I think I already configure all the attributes like,

```
visibility = not show individually
stock = in stock
price = also set
status = enable
```

anything I missed? Because when go to my configurable product there is nothing as Associated Products.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hello Quan,

To associate them
not needed:

visibilty = not show inidividually
stock = in stock
price = also set
status = enable

needed:
attribute set = the same as configurable product (check configurable product attribute in admin section)

to create a config
Beside this you need to make sure, that the attributes you want to be configurable are NOT system, "Global", input type "Dropdown" and "allowed for configurables"

to show them in frontend
Only the simple ones which are in stock and enabled are shown in frontend, might be an indexing issue?

Thanks!
```